# How to sparate various Panels in cardlayout NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I am using NetBeans 7.2. I have a JFrame with Card Layout having one Main Panel and Several Sub Panels. As you can guess all auto generated Swing component definitions are declared in single file, and its all messed up.

[image]

How can I separate these panels say in a package, to make it more modular? Or am I taking completely wrong approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create `JPanel` forms with the builder tool. `New -> Swing Forms -> JPanel Form`. Then to see them in the design view, just drag and drop them onto the card layout panel as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22194357/2587435)

Answer (score 0):

slightly wrong approach.. if you want to make the panels something like modular, just create a new panel class inside the package, not many panels on the same class.. create new panel class and pass it to ur main panel..